# How do I copy all Files and Sub-Folders from One Folder to another Folder in same AWS S3 bucket in Ruby

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created a folder named **Backup** in an S3 bucket name **Houston**. I have another folder name **Logs** where I can see all application logs.
**Logs** folder may contain multiple files and sub-folders in it. I want to copy all files and sub-folders from **Logs** folder to **Backup** folder.

I am using Ruby AWS sdk.

Comment: Would you be willing to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/)? It has in-built commands like `aws s3 cp --recursive` and `aws s3 sync` that can copy files and sub-folders. Or, do you need to do it via your own code?

Comment: Yes @JohnRotenstein. I am looking for Rest API approach instead AWS CLI

Comment: Is this a continuing requirement? If so, you might consider using [Amazon S3 Same Region Replication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/replication.html), which will automatically copy files between buckets as soon as they are created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Amazon S3 API call to copy folders.

You would need to:

- List the contents of the source bucket
- Loop through each object and use `CopyObject()` to copy the object to another location

From [Copy an Object Using the AWS SDK for Ruby - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CopyingObjectUsingRuby.html):

```rb
require 'aws-sdk-s3'

source_bucket_name = '*** Provide bucket name ***'
target_bucket_name = '*** Provide bucket name ***'
source_key = '*** Provide source key ***'
target_key = '*** Provide target key ***'

begin
  s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new(region: 'us-west-2')
  s3.copy_object(bucket: target_bucket_name, copy_source: source_bucket_name + '/' + source_key, key: target_key)
rescue StandardError => ex
  puts 'Caught exception copying object ' + source_key + ' from bucket ' + source_bucket_name + ' to bucket ' + target_bucket_name + ' as ' + target_key + ':'
  puts ex.message
end

puts 'Copied ' +  source_key + ' from bucket ' + source_bucket_name + ' to bucket ' + target_bucket_name + ' as ' + target_key
```

Comment: To copy_object() method requires copy_source and key attribute as mandatory. What does the key attribute mean here?
```
client.copy_object({
  bucket: "destinationbucket", 
  copy_source: "/sourcebucket/HappyFacejpg", 
  key: "HappyFaceCopyjpg", 
})
```

Are you suggest me to use like below
```
client.copy_object({
  bucket: "Houston", 
  copy_source: "/Houston/HappyFacejpg", 
  key: "HappyFaceCopyjpg", 
})

```
I am not sure what do we need to pass for the key attribute.

Comment: I have added a Ruby code example. `bucket` and `key` define the destination, while `copy_source` defines the source `bucket/path`. A `key` is the filename of an object including the full path.

Comment: Thanks John. It's working. But is there a way to do a bulk copy/duplicate/clone the folder something like that. Because it is taking more time since the folder size is huge and copy_object is copying objects between 1 by 1.

Comment: The Amazon S3 API only accepts one file at a time. You could, however, issue multiple copy commands in parallel (if your programming language supports this). As an example, the AWS CLI issues parallel copy commands to make the copy process faster.